# Token must be defined! at new ReflectiveKey error

Tags: angular, typescript

I use the latest stable Angular 2.4.4 version.

Somehow, when I declare service resolver and register it in the component module and in a router, it fails.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { PGService, PG} from '../pg/';

@Injectable()
export class HomeServiceResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(
        private pgService: PGService
    ) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<PG> {
        return Observable.from([new PG()]);
    }
}
```

with this strange error

```
vendor.dll.js:73630 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Token must be defined!
Error: Token must be defined!
    at new ReflectiveKey (vendor.dll.js:54947) [angular]
    at KeyRegistry.get (vendor.dll.js:55000) [angular]
    at Function.ReflectiveKey.get (vendor.dll.js:54965) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (vendor.dll.js:100258) [angular]
    at MyAppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (vendor.dll.js:74217) [angular]
    at PreActivation.getToken (vendor.dll.js:25710) [angular]
    at :9000/vendor.dll.js:25697:51 [angular]
    at :9000/vendor.dll.js:9128:86 [angular]
    at forEach (vendor.dll.js:9106) [angular]
    at waitForMap (vendor.dll.js:9126) [angular]
    at PreActivation.resolveNode (vendor.dll.js:25696) [angular]
    at PreActivation.runResolve (vendor.dll.js:25683) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (vendor.dll.js:25499) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (vendor.dll.js:17439) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:501) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:486) [angular]
    at :9000/polyfills.bundle.js:3838:17 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.dll.js:42772) [angular]
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:274) [angular]
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:151) [<root> => angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:433) [<root>]
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:349) [<root>]
    ErrorHandler.handleError @ vendor.dll.js:73630
    next @ vendor.dll.js:53364
    schedulerFn @ vendor.dll.js:55453
    SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ vendor.dll.js:588
    SafeSubscriber.next @ vendor.dll.js:537
    Subscriber._next @ vendor.dll.js:490
    Subscriber.next @ vendor.dll.js:454
    Subject.next @ vendor.dll.js:4491
    EventEmitter.emit @ vendor.dll.js:55439
    NgZone.triggerError @ vendor.dll.js:42841
    onHandleError @ vendor.dll.js:42802
    webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:246
    webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:129
    _loop_1 @ zone.js:444
    drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:453
    ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:349
    zone.js:420 Unhandled Promise rejection: Token must be defined! ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Token must be defined!
    at new ReflectiveKey (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:54947:19…, __zone_symbol__stack: "Error: Token must be defined!↵    at new Reflectiv…/localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:17439:27) [angular]", __zone_symbol__message: "Token must be defined!"} Error: Token must be defined!
    at new ReflectiveKey (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:54947:19) [angular]
    at KeyRegistry.get (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:55000:39) [angular]
    at Function.ReflectiveKey.get (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:54965:35) [angular]
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:100258:94) [angular]
    at MyAppModuleInjector.NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:74217:52) [angular]
    at PreActivation.getToken (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:25710:25) [angular]
    at http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:25697:51 [angular]
    at http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:9128:86 [angular]
    at forEach (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:9106:13) [angular]
    at waitForMap (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:9126:5) [angular]
    at PreActivation.resolveNode (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:25696:101) [angular]
    at PreActivation.runResolve (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:25683:81) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:25499:30) [angular]
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:9000/vendor.dll.js:17439:27) [angular]
    consoleError @ zone.js:420
    _loop_1 @ zone.js:449
    drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:453
    ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:349
    zone.js:422 ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Token must be defined!
    Error: Token must be defined!
        at new…, rejection: ZoneAwareError, promise: ZoneAwarePromise, zone: Zone, task: ZoneTask…}
```

What is the possible reason?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. It has something to do with the placement of the resolver service class. Try placing it in the same folder as the component and I've got it working.

Comment: Thank you for answering!! We had a resolver within the same typescript file but it was re-used. This worked for a while, but stopped working all of a sudden. We moved the resolver to it's own file and it fixed it.  We still use it from other folders but this answer definitely helped us to a solution.